# Does an absolute pathname on the unix filesystem need to begin with a "/"?

Tags: unix

What are other restrictions on what an absolute pathname can be?

It seems that the only restrictions are that it must begin with a "/", and the following sequence of ascii characters must consist of segments of ascii characters each separated by "/".

Note: I'm trying to figure out the name space of a function that maps pathnames to files.

Edit: It turns out that for my homework, my reasoning on the restrictions is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The length of a pathname name cannot exceed PATH_MAX - see /usr/include/limits.h or sysconf(3).

The length of a file cannot exceed NAME_MAX which is filesystem dependent - see fpathconf(3) or [pathconf](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/pathconf.html).

An absolute path does start with '/'

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is it depends on the filesystem used, but you can force a specific charset from the kernel.

The long version is most don't have many restrictions, there are some which will even let you use '/' or '\0' as a valid character in a file name, however dealing with that in software is crazy, so noone really uses that "feature". If for example you map a FAT filesystem you will be restricted to what's legal on that (only ascii). I use ext4 and reiserfs4 which allows everything except '/' and '\0'. I use the utf-8 charset so i can have file names with all global characters in their names (I have a few files with japanese or russian names - mostly music from those countries).